# import module then import specific function - more pythonic way to treat import

Tags: python

I'm considering which is more pythonic,

```
import math
from math import sqrt
```

or

```
import math
sqrt = math.sqrt
```

I've written a code that use `sqrt` for many times, so using `math.sqrt` every time is a bit weird thing to do.
In this code, sometimes I use `math.(something)` such as `math.pi`, `math.ceil` or so.
Now you can use the former or latter way to use `sqrt` and `math`. Is there any reason to determine which is the better?

Comment: use the top one, more idiomatic, also in PEP8 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Comment: Top one. Both approaches may do the same thing in the end but the first one is definetely "more pythonic".

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `from math import sqrt` without the need to also add `import math` on top?

Comment: @toti08 I use `math.pi`, `math.ceil` and so, and want them to declared as `math.foo` since simply write `pi`, `ceil` is somewhat confusing.

Comment: @NaokiNakamura check PEP8 posted on the first comment, is says _If this spelling causes local name clashes, then spell them explicitly_, meaning if these names generate confusion in your code it's ok to just `import math` and then refer to these as `math.pi` or `math.ceil`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments,
The former one

```
import math
from math import sqrt
```

is more readable (and pythonic.)
This solution is acceptable, despite the best one is to use simply `import math` and then using `math.sqrt`.

Comment: I think that if you write `from math import sqrt` you don't need to also `import math`.

Comment: @toti08 Here's my try on python3.7.0 repl `from math import sqrt` then `math.pi` got this: `NameError: name 'math' is not defined`

Comment: if you type `from math import sqrt` then you should just use `sqrt` and not `math.sqrt`.

Comment: And for using `pi` you should do something like `from math import sqrt, ip` and whatever you need to use from math.